# HTML picture slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, jss

im somewhat new to html, css or java script and so far i ran into a bit of a problem and wanted to ask for advice because watching youtube videos did not exactly solve the problem or im missing a point somewhere in them.
Anyway the question i wanted to ask is how do i make my arrows work meaning when i click on them for them to change pictures so im also using keyframes in my css but i wish to have an option to let users change pictures them self by clicking on arrow keys, thanks a lot for any help in advance, would love to have some cirtique from what ive written so far as well and how to improve it.

Bellow is the code. (might not look quite as it should due to missing pictures but i hope you will get the point).

```js
const date = new Date();

const renderCalendar = () => {
  date.setDate(1);

  const monthDays = document.querySelector(".days");

  const lastDay = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1, 0
    ).getDate();

  const prevLastDay = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),0
    ).getDate();

  const firstDayIndex = date.getDay();

  const lastDayIndex = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  ).getDay();
  
  const nextDays = 7 - lastDayIndex - 1;

  const months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  document.querySelector(".date h1").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];

  document.querySelector(".date p").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();

  let days = "";

  for (let x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--) {
    days += `<div class="prev-date">${prevLastDay - x + 1}</div>`;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
    if (i === new Date().getDate() && date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) {
      days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
    } else {
      days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
    }
  }

  for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) {
    days += `<div class="next-date">${j}</div>`;
  }
  monthDays.innerHTML = days;
};

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  renderCalendar();
});

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  renderCalendar();
});

renderCalendar();



var slider_img = document.querySelector('.FirstHbox');
var images = ['RegPic0.jpg', 'RegPic1.jpg', 'RegPic2.jpg', 'RegPic3.jpg'];
var i = 0;
 
function side_slideL(){
  if(i <= 0) i = images.length
  i--;
  return setImg();
}

function side_slideR(){
  
}

function setImg(){
  return slider_img.setAttribute('src', '/' + images[i]);
}
// var indexValue = 1;
// showImg(indexValue);
// function side_slide(e) {
//   showImg(indexValue +=e)
// }
// function showImg(e) {
//   var i;
//   const img = document.querySelectorAll("img")
//   if(e > img.length) {
//     indexValue = 1
//   }
//   if(e < 1) {
//     indexValue = img.length
//   }
//   for(i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
//     img[i].style.display = "none";
//   }
//   img[indexValue - 1].style.display = "grid";
// }
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header2 h1{
    color: teal;
    text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px black
}
.h3 {
    color: greenyellow;
    text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px green;
}

.h2 {
    color: greenyellow;
}

.h4 {
    color: greenyellow;
}
body {
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
}

.header2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    background-color:rgba(70, 13, 16, 0.575);

}

.inner_header {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin:  auto;
}

.logo_container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

.logo_container h1{
    color:wheat;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation a{
    height:100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
}

.navigation a li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    color: wheat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  
}

.navigation a li:hover{
    background-color: #167e56;
}

.mainbox{
    border: blue;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: auto;
}

.box{
    color:royalblue;
    border:#ff6a00 2px solid;
    background-color:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:10%;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;

}


.box1{
    color:royalblue;
    border:#ff6a00 2px solid;
    background-color:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:70%;
    margin-top:40px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
   
}   



.FirstHbox{
    display: grid;
    border: #AAFFAA 2px solid;
    color: wheat;
    background-image: url("RegPic0.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    animation: FirstHbox 50s infinite alternate 5s ;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px whitesmoke;  
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes FirstHbox {
    form{
        background-image: url("RegPic0.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: center;
    }
    25%{
        background-image: url("RegPic1.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: center;
    }
    50%{
        background-image: url("RegPic2.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: center;
    }
    75%{
        background-image: url("RegPic3.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: center;
    }
    100%{
        background-image: url("RegPic4.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: center;
    }

}

.FirstHPCollum{
    padding: 1%;
}
.HomePan1{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    font-family: "Marcellus SC", serif;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.HomePan2{
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    font-family: "Marcellus SC", serif;
}
.FirstHboxButton{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    
}
.RegButtonHP{
    border: yellow 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.FoundryButtonHP{
    border: springgreen 2px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.nav-HP-left-button:hover{
    background-color: teal;
}

.nav-HP-left-button{
    background: url("ArrowLeft.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    height: 20%;
    width: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    margin: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}
.nav-HP-right-button:hover{
    background-color: teal;
}

.nav-HP-right-button{
    background: url("ArrowLeft.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    height: 20%;
    width: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    margin: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;    
}

.MainBox{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;

}
.NewsFeedFooter{
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
}
.NewsFeed{
    border: #1e2124 2% solid;
    color: wheat;
    /* background-image: url("Anchor\ Weight.png"); */
    background-color:  #363535;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#363535, rgb(14, 9, 9));
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;    
    margin-top: 1%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5% 5% 10% 5%;
    border-bottom: none;
    
}
.NewsFeed p {
    text-indent: 5%;
    font-family: 'Zen Dots', cursive;
}


.Footer{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("Footer\ Smoke.png");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -15%;
    position: relative;
}

.SideBar{    

    width: 20%;
    position: relative;   
    display: inline; 
    /* justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */

    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 0.4%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;


}

.LogInTab{
    background-image: url("Legend_1.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    padding-left: 7%;
    padding-right: 7%;
}

.LogInTab button{
    margin-top: 5%;
    

}
.LogInTab input{
    width: 80%;
}



.Calendar{
    width: fit-content;
    height: 50%;
    border: teal 2px solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color:blue;
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px black;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    
}

.Month {
    background-color: #167e56;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 3%;
    text-align: center;
    
  }

.Month i {
    font-size: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
.Month h1 {
    font-size: 160%;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
  }
  
.month p {
    font-size: 100%;
  }

.weekdays {    
    padding: 0 4%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:black;
  }

.weekdays div {
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1%;
    width: calc(100% / 7);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

.days {
    font-size: 170%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1%;
  }

.days div {
    margin: 1%;
    width: calc(86% / 7);
    /* width: calc(86% / 7); margin + padding *7 - 100% */
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: background-color 2s;
   }

.days div:hover:not(.today) {
    background-color: #262626;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    cursor: pointer;
  }


.prev-date, .next-date {
  opacity: 0.5;
} 

.today {
    background-color: red;
  }

/* fieldset:nth-of-type(odd)
    {
        float: left;
    } */



input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
    color: yellow;
    }

::placeholder {
    color: red;

}

input:required:invalid {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

input:valid {
    background-color: #AAFFAA;
}


/* @media screen and  (max-width:480px) {
    .box1{
        display: flexbox;
        margin: auto;


    }
    .box{
        display: none;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .header{
        display: none;
    }
} */

.test{
    background: url("ArrowLeft.png");
    margin: 500px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="This is Clash of the worlds main homepage where you can find introduction to the page and campaign it self" />
        <title>COTW Sarleon HomePage</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mukta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marcellus+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zen+Dots&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"/>
        <link type="Javascript" href="main.js"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>

        
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="inner_header">
                <div class="logo_container">
                    <h1>Sarleon<span>Saga</span></h1>
                </div>

                <ul class="navigation">
                    <a href="/Home"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="/Foundry"><li>Foundry</li></a>
                    <a href="/Login"><li>Login</li></a>
                    <a href="/Register"><li>Register</li></a>
                    <a href="/Forums"><li>Forums</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <fieldset class=FirstHbox>
            <div class="FirstHPCollum">
                <div >
                    <h1 class="HomePan1">Register today!</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3 class="HomePan2">The adventure awaits.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="FirstHboxButton" >
                <div class="RegButtonHP">
                    <a> Register </a>
                </div>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div class="FoundryButtonHP">
                    <a> Go to Foundry</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div onclick="side_slideL" class="nav-HP-left-button"></div>
            <div onclick="side_slideR" class="nav-HP-right-button"></div>
        </fieldset>
        
        <div class="MainBox">
            <div class="NewsFeedFooter">
                <fieldset class="NewsFeed">
                    <h1>News</h1>
                    <br><br>
                    
                    
                </fieldset>
                <div class="Footer">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="SideBar">
                <div class="LogInTab" >
                    <div>Username:</div>
                    <input type="text">
                    <div>Password:</div>
                    <input type="text">
                    <br>
                    <button >Login</button>
            
                </div>



                <div class="Calendar">
                    <div class="Month">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
                        <div class="date">
                            <h1></h1>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="weekdays">
                        <div>Mon</div>
                        <div>Tue</div>
                        <div>Wed</div>
                        <div>Thu</div>
                        <div>Fri</div>
                        <div>Sat</div>
                        <div>Sun</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="days"></div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
           





    </body>
    <script src="Js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not seeing how the current day or last day comes into play with a "slider".

Comment: I can't even see any arrows that you mentioned in question.

Comment: the arrows are located in html and css as            
 <div onclick="side_slideL" class="nav-HP-left-button"></div>
 <div onclick="side_slideR" class="nav-HP-right-button"></div>

and
.nav-HP-left-button or .nav-HP-left-button:hover ect...